# Wrong math in sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, math

so i am working with sqlite3 database for my application and the results of simple math calculations are wrong and I am concerned due to this.. so here goes, i have to find the netflow of incoming and outgoing stock and their flow is being recorded in two separate tables purchases and stock outflow respectively.. i group the purchases and used (outflow) material in the query by their product id and add their quantities from both the tables and then subtract the added quantities from the two tables to get the left quantity of that product or netflow of that product but sqlite3 database fails to do even simple math,

for ex - when a product is purchased in two different quantities 8 and 4 respectively the answer must be 12 but it gives 24 and when the same product is used twice in different quantities like 7 and 4 the answer must be 11 but it gives 22..

below is the SQL query i wrote to find the netflow of each product seperately,

```
                  SELECT p.product_id,
                         SUM(p.quantity) AS total_inflow,
                         SUM(s.quantity) AS total_outflow,
                         SUM(p.quantity) - SUM(s.quantity) AS quantity_left,
                         s.UOM

                  FROM purchases p
                  INNER JOIN stock_out s ON p.product_id = s.product_id

                  GROUP BY p.product_id, s.product_id
```

Comment: Please add a test case in the form of `CREATE TABLE` statements, plus a few `INSERT` statements.  Then provide the actual result of that test, plus your expected result, given that specific data.

Comment: Note: Your `GROUP BY` only requires `p.product_id` or `s.product_id`, not both and your SELECT list contains `s.UOM` which is likely not functionally dependent on the `GROUP BY` terms.  That might be the source of the misunderstanding.  Also, `SUM(p.quantity)` might not produce what you expected, due to the `JOIN`.  This will depend on the type of relationship, (1-1 or 1-N).

Comment: If you have one row of in_flow and 2 rows of out_flow for the same product, the in_flow quantity will be seen twice by the SUM and produce twice the expected value.  The same is true of the quantity sums of out_flow.  This is all due to the JOIN behavior.   Your test case will show which case you have.  But your logic is susceptible to both problems.

Comment: so what i get from your comment is that the problem is likely occurring due to the join statement, so how should i write the query without the join statement so that the problem doesn't occur and the needed task is also done.. any inputs on this??

Comment: See the 2 answers below.  Both approaches can work, once any typos are corrected.

Comment: sure will try these sql queries

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than one row of either in_flow or out_flow or both, the SUM of the other quantity is impacted due to the JOIN operation.

To address the `JOIN` issue, you can do something like this, as an example.  To address the case of in_flow and no out_flow, and we want to show those results as well, we can use an outer join for this (adjustment made).

If there's a chance of out_flow with no corresponding in_flow, we could use a FULL OUTER JOIN.  I suspect that may not be necessary in this case.

```
WITH in_flow AS (
        SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS total_inflow
          FROM purchases
         GROUP BY product_id
     )
   , out_flow AS (
        SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS total_outflow
          FROM stock_out
         GROUP BY product_id
     )
SELECT in_flow.product_id
     , total_inflow, COALESCE(total_outflow, 0) AS total_outflow
     , total_inflow - COALESCE(total_outflow, 0) AS remaining
  FROM      in_flow
  LEFT JOIN out_flow
    ON in_flow.product_id = out_flow.product_id
;
```

Comment: This way you will filter out any product for which there is a row in only one of the 2 tables.

Comment: @forpas That's correct.  This one assumed there is always in_flow for any out_flow.  You can't send out something that you never had... and the poster didn't want results for products that had no out_flow.  But, as always, this will depend on the complete requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate separately in the 2 tables and use `UNION ALL` for the results.
Then aggregate again:

```
SELECT product_id, 
       SUM(total_inflow) AS total_inflow, 
       SUM(total_outflow) AS total_outflow,
       SUM(total_inflow) - SUM(total_outflow) AS quantity_left
FROM (
  SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS total_inflow, 0 AS total_outflow
  FROM purchases 
  GROUP BY product_id 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT product_id, 0, SUM(quantity) 
  FROM stock_out 
  GROUP BY product_id
) 
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the `UNION ALL` operation.

Comment: @JonArmstrong I thought I did, but no... Thanks